# Same Disqus comment in multiple blog post (asynchronous) using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, disqus

Hi I am creating my personal blog using angularjs and bootstrap. I am trying to configure Disqus for comments. But the problem is that, same comments are shown for all the posts. I am using angularjs directive for Disqus.

```
<div ng-disqus 
       disqus-shortname="abhishekprakashcom"
       disqus-identifier="{{ blog.TITLE }}" 
       disqus-title="{{ blog.TITLE }}"
       ready-to-bind="{{ contentLoaded }}">
</div>
```

I have used the directive from [here](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/disqus). The only modification I made is changed the directive from an element to an attribute.

I really trying hard for this. Initially I was trying to embed the script directly but it was also not working. You can check the my [blog](http://abhishekprakash.com/#/blog) (it does not have the directive implementation as I am trying out the same in my localhost)

Please let me know if any further clarification is required.

Thanks.

This is the output from Batrang

```
     { 
        disqus_shortname: abhishekprakashcom
        disqus_identifier: 3
        disqus_title: Another Test.
        disqus_category_id: 3
        readyToBind: true
        disqus_url: null
        disqus_disable_mobile: null
     }
```

I have added disqus_category_id as well and every thing is changing on changing the blog, but nothing happens.

Comment: Seems like you are just using the same identifier -- `disqus-identifier="{{ article.id }}` -- or your variable is only getting set once...

Comment: But disqus-identifier="{{ blog.TITLE }} should change as the title is changing everytime I am loading a new blog.

Comment: Yes for the next time all the variables are resetting to null. Edited the question with the Batrang output

Comment: I have fixed the null issue. I have added disqus_category_id as well and every thing is changing on changing the blog, but I am still getting same comment on all the blogs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been working on the similar set of technologies and got stuck on the same problem as you.

There is a custom directive from Michael Bromley for disqus on Angular SPA's that should help you out. [Github page](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/disqus)

==================================================================================
IMP:

setting up hashbang URL's.

It is one prequisite from DISQUS, hence cant be helped. It seems it only recognizes hashbang urls.

in your route config, add :

> $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

This should give you a xxxxx.com/!#xxxxx/xxxx kind of URL.

you can add `$locationProvider.html5Mode('true')` also for clean URL's but the experience is a bit buggy with DISQUS (my personal opinion).

After the URL's are set , This is the directive he created, copy it where ever you are storing the directives.

```
.directive('dirDisqus', function($window) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        disqus_shortname: '@disqusShortname',
        disqus_identifier: '@disqusIdentifier',
        disqus_title: '@disqusTitle',
        disqus_url: '@disqusUrl',
        disqus_category_id: '@disqusCategoryId',
        disqus_disable_mobile: '@disqusDisableMobile',
        readyToBind: "@"
    },
    template: '<div id="disqus_thread"></div><a href="http://disqus.com" class="dsq-brlink">comments powered by <span class="logo-disqus">Disqus</span></a>',
    link: function(scope) {

        scope.$watch("readyToBind", function(isReady) {

            // If the directive has been called without the 'ready-to-bind' attribute, we
            // set the default to "true" so that Disqus will be loaded straight away.
            if ( !angular.isDefined( isReady ) ) {
                isReady = "true";
            }
            if (scope.$eval(isReady)) {
                // put the config variables into separate global vars so that the Disqus script can see them
                $window.disqus_shortname = scope.disqus_shortname;
                $window.disqus_identifier = scope.disqus_identifier;
                $window.disqus_title = scope.disqus_title;
                $window.disqus_url = scope.disqus_url;
                $window.disqus_category_id = scope.disqus_category_id;
                $window.disqus_disable_mobile = scope.disqus_disable_mobile;

                // get the remote Disqus script and insert it into the DOM
                var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
                dsq.src = '//' + scope.disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
                (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

});

In your html page:

```
<dir-disqus disqus-shortname="xxxxxxx"
                    disqus-identifier={{scope.Title}}
                    disqus-title={{scope.Title}}
                    disqus-url={{scope.url}} /* I set window.location.href in my controller to pass the url*/
                    readytobind="true">
        </dir-disqus>
```

This should do :)

Comment: I have changed the url to hashbang format. But now I am getting We were unable to load Disqus. If you are a moderator please see our troubleshooting guide. In fact I was getting this error since last 2 days, after I did some modifications..I am not not able to figure out what I did.

Comment: It has no effect what so ever.

Comment: i was xhecking on my localhost, and when i tested on my server it worked. thanks a lot :)

Comment: glad to help! :) "We were unable to load Disqus. If you are a moderator please see our troubleshooting guide." for this error, if you see it again. you need to reset your account in disqus. That shoul d work.